# Skiasharp, error in UWP platform 0x747219F2 (ucrtbase.dll)

Tags: uwp, skiasharp

i run a simple sample using SkiaSharp (by NuGet) on UWP project.
I'm trying to load a png image using `SKBitmap.Decode(filename)` but this error is thrown:

> 0x747219F2 (ucrtbase.dll)
>
> An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal.

Same sample in Windows Forms runs without problems.

Comment: What is the `filename`? Could you post the path? Is the file part of your application package?

Comment: It's an abosulte path in my pc hard drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because UWP runs in a sandbox, you can only access a limited number of locations in the file system without additional permissions. In this case, you the code cannot access an arbitrary bitmap by absolute file path.

You can access files in your application's install folder and in its `ApplicationData`.

The easiest solution would be to add the bitmap to your UWP project as a `Content` file, for example to the `Assets` folder and then access it like this:

```
var packagePath = Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
var filename = Path.Combine( packagePath, "Assets/YourImage.png" );
SKBitmap.Decode(filename);
```

This should work as expected.